# sql management crashes when getting database list

Tags: database, crash, ssms

everbody.

when we are connect our sql 2014 servers, its connect. but sql management is crashes when the click databases link. it's says: "expanding." and crashed..

server's sql version and our sql version is same.

what can we do?

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried connecting to this instance from other computers? This seems like an issue with the SSMS install on the workstation you're using. I've had several instances where databases have gone down or been offlined and SSMS may error out while trying to read DB info, but it doesn't crash.

Comment: Try rebooting your machine and ensuring that you have the latest update packs loaded for SSMS,  I would also try from another machine to narrow down if it is machine specific or not